# Java Runtime Environment | DeploymentRuleSet.jar | ruleset.xml

Tags: java, xml

I am having a problem with getting a ruleset.xml file to function as expected. I am using a Windows 10 client for testing and to keep things simple, i'm trying to get http://javatester.org/version.html to use version 1.8.0_92 as specified within my ruleset.xml file (below).

[Deployment Rule Set - ruleset.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KicGW.gif)

There are two versions of JRE installed on my machine i.e. 1.6.0_25 as well as that already mentioned above. Unfortunately, when i browse to the above URL, the instance reported is the 1.6.0_25 version which is not what i want.

In terms of the DeploymentRuleSet.jar file, as you can see this is valid and i have appropriately signed the certificate etc. Additionally, if i remove some essential content from the ruleset.xml file then the DeploymentRuleSet.jar becomes invalid which further suggests that up to the point of reading the file everything is OK...i just can't seem to figure out why this isn't applying. In fact, i've even tried blocking everything by default yet this also doesn't work...Any help and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure this out.

The short answer is that I had two different versions of Java running, however one of those versions was x64 whereas the other version was (obviously) an x86 version. The DeploymentRuleSet.xml was working as expected however the x64 version was not firing. It wasn't firing because because i needed to add the site in question into the 'Trusted Sites'. This was due to the enhanced restrictions within IE and come as a result of the 'Enhanced Protection Mode' and 'Enhanced Protection Mode for 64 bit Processes' (i believe it comes under this from the top of my head). Adding the sites in question to the Trusted Sites is not a security issue (for us)given these are national systems we know and use.